# Big d3 graph rendering issues

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to render a D3 force layout with about 5k nodes and 25k links. I am getting the following error, with no further hints:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Smaller graphs are correctly rendered. I know it might seem an odd question, but can't provide further details; what might be the reason causing this? I suspect layout properties might affect its performance, but don't have previous experience tuning them (ie how each of them affects the rendering process).

I am currently initializing the force layout like this:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .linkDistance(180)
  .charge(-120)
  .on('tick', tick);
```

Comment: From my experience using `d3` it is not suitable for large datasets. A force layout is especially computationally expensive. From the error, it seems that there are so many function calls that your browser can't handle them anymore. This is a common problem with recursive functions. From my chats with data visualisations experts; usually it goes from `d3` to `canvas` to `webgl` based on requirements. In your case the bottleneck is probably the force layout itself, which is hard to calculate.

Comment: This error is most likely unrelated to the amount of data -- adding more nodes/links doesn't increase the level of nesting/recursion. I would have a look at the data itself and see if there are any inconsistencies there.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff data looks fine (no NaN in x/y attributes, this problem was commented in https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/892). It might be a possible bug (see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2408).